# mongodb works when executing the binary, but not when starting the service ("Unable to determine status of lock file")

Tags: mongodb

I know this is a duplicate, but all answers suggest either changing owner of the data directory to mongodb:mongodb or permissions to 777.  I've tried both and it hasn't worked.

I have a machine whose sole purpose is to run mongodb.  I'm logged
in as root. I'd like to change my data directory to `/root/mongodb`.  I have updated `dbpath` in `/etc/mongod.conf`.

If I run `systemctl start mongod` or `sudo systemctl start mongod`, I get the following error:

```
2018-02-07T18:39:53.246+0100 I STORAGE [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28596 Unable to determine status of lock file in the data directory /root/mongodb: boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied: "/root/mongodb/mongod.lock", terminating
```

I've tried `chown -R mongodb:mongodb /root/mongodb` and `chmod -R 777 /root/mongodb`, but still see the same error.  This are the permissions after running both:

`drwxrwxrwx  4 mongodb mongodb 4096 Feb  7 18:27 mongodb`

However, if I run `mongodb --dbpath=/root/mongodb`, it starts up fine.

Version info:

```
db version v3.4.11
git version: 34f5bec2c9d827d71828fe858167f89a28b29a2a
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: ubuntu1604
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: It's a terrible idea. I'd strongly recommend to move mongodb files out of `/root/` directory. The error is because you need to apply permissions to the whole path, not only the target directory. mongod started as a service with mongodb user don't have access to `/root` directory. It doesn't matter how carelessly you open other directories down the path, mongod can't access it.

Comment: @AlexBlex Thank you for that pointer.  Moving it out of /root and to somewhere where I can chown the entire path seems to have worked.  (It's not a production system and has a funny partitioning where all the space was allocated to /root, hence the odd setup.)  If you provide a short answer just saying the entire path needs to be chowned, I'll accept it.